# How to load data into MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to load an array of dictionary items into single MySQL table.

Each dictionary object is a mixture of string and int types (20 elements in total)

The profiling code below terminates at the 320th char of each returned row and I can't see if the problem is in the actual insert query because of data problems.

Looking at either  `cursor._last_executed`  or  `cursor.statement` return  `None`  which is helping either

How can I get the FULL profiling insert statement?

Is there a better way to load this data (approx 800-1000 records to load)

Thanks

```
def load_to_mysql(data):
conn = mysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='used',passwd='pwd', db='zz_datamotive')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for dict in data:
    placeholder = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(dict))
    stmt = 'INSERT INTO `table` ({columns}) VALUES ({values})'.format(columns=', '.join(dict.keys()), values=placeholder)
    cursor.execute('set profiling = 1')
    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt , list(dict.values()))
        cursor.commit()
    except Exception:
        cursor.execute('show profiles')
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)        
    cursor.execute('set profiling = 0')
```

Comment: suggest trying increasing the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to see if that fixes it. Use the maximum, AFAIK there's no downside to a large value. Would be be nice if the python connector provided the equivalent of [the C mysql-set-local-infile-handler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-set-local-infile-handler.html)

Comment: I've finally fixed it and had nothing to do with above :-)      The dictionary object I was passing in had a '#' symbol as part of the keyname and this was causing the problem.  Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

For large data instead of insert statement you can also consider loading data from file.

```
sql_string = "load data local infile " + directory + " into table XYZ;"
```

Comment: A idea but I am scraping data from a website trying to avoid saving files locally.